# LinearLayout won't fill parent; instead if fits to the smallest width view in it

Tags: android-layout

I have a view that looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/title_icon"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/title_icon" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/title_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:text="@string/activity_complete"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/status_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="8dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView android:id="@+id/message_text" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:textSize="10dp"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/main_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:padding="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that the main LinearLayout view doesn't match_parent or fill_parent.  It seems to want to only contain the smallest item within it.  In my case it will result in a width the same as main_image, cutting off the content of everything else.  However, if I set main_image to visibility.gone then it will match the width of message_text.

I've tried removing everything except main_image and the main LinearLayout still only fits the image width.

The other thing is that this layout is inflated into another LinearLayout which is set to fill_parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the ImageView in another LinearLayout fixed the issue.

Comment: It seems like this is only necessary some of the time, but I can't figure out what the conditions are.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem -- adding a LinearLayout configured to "match_parent" to another LinearLayout, but the inner layout did not fill the outer one properly.

Initially I was doing this to add the layout:

```
LinearLayout inner = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inner, null);
outer.addView(inner, 0);
```

After a few minutes of exasperation I tried this instead:

```
LinearLayout inner = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inner, outer);
```

And `inner` matched the `outer` parent width and height.